# Absolute path from relative path and an anchor file in PHP

Tags: php

How can I compute the absolute path of a file, when I've got a relative path and another absolute path which should act as an anchor point.

For example:

```
$anchor = '/tmp/uploads/abcd1234/import.xml';
$relative = 'main_image.png';
$abs = foo($anchor, $relative); # fn `foo` is what I'm looking for
assert($abs == '/tmp/uploads/abcd1234/main_image.png');
```

or slightly more complicated:

```
$anchor = '/tmp/uploads/abcd1234/import.xml';
$relative = '../resource/dummy.jpg';
$abs = foo($anchor, $relative); # fn `foo` is what I'm looking for
assert($abs == '/tmp/uploads/resource/dummy.jpg');
```

Comment: How could we know that the absolute URL starts from `/tmp/uploads/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realpath(dirname($anchor).'/'.$relative)`

Comment: That was my first attempt too, but `realpath` only works when the file already exists. When the file doesn't exist yet (for example when I want to calculate the path where to store the file too which I just created), then `realpath` returns `false` as stated in the PHP documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php

Comment: Just found a solution to the `realpath` issue myself when posting the manual link. Using the replacement function for `realpath` posted by some user in the comment section of the PHP manual should do the job even for non-existing files: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php#84012

Comment: Glad to (indirectly) help :)

Comment: Also note, `/./` and `/../` paths work for any (and all) functions that handle files. So you can just save the file with the dirty path and then once it's created update to a clean `realpath()`. But in order to enforce some security checks (like forced prefix), it's better to parse the path before writing anything to it. Note, if you're using user-generated filenames, `[\\x00-\\x1F/\\?%*:|"<>]` class of characters is able to cause disruption. Take extreme care for `['"*\\]` if you run any shell command on the files, it's exploitable same as SQL injection.